# DIY Heat Treating Home For Bugs - Danger To My Gas Pipe?

Tags: heating, gas, pest-control, natural-gas

**Actual Question:**

My apartment has a gas line that is used for my oven and I'm wondering if anything needs to be done with that before I can heat treat my apartment. The apartments temperature will be at 150 degree Fahrenheit for almost an entire day.

**Context:**

I'm trying to get rid of [Bird Mites](https://britishbirdcontrol.co.uk/service/heat-treatment-bird-mites/) and I'm considering doing [heat treatments](https://britishbirdcontrol.co.uk/service/heat-treatment-bird-mites/) myself using the [ePro 400 XP Electric Heat Bed Bug package](https://www.greentechheat.com/cart.php#!/ePro-400XP-Electric-Heat-Bed-Bug-Package/p/400548567/category=14085535) from the company [Green Tech Heat](https://www.greentechheat.com/).

[image]

The reason I am thinking about forking over the large sum of $2,000 USD to buy this and do it myself versus going with a professional company is because I have most of my belongings in a storage unit that would need to be treated, my apartment itself with other belongings of mine would need to be treated, and my car needs to be treated. I'm moving out of my current apartment and into a new house so there isn't really a good way for a professional company to heat treat my belongings in my storage unit because I wouldn't be able to do it in the storage unit and I don't want to move those belongings into my new house and risk infecting the new house.

So my plan is to buy the [Dr. Infrared Heater DR-122X4 Large Size Bedbug Treatment System](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073VPTWWC) and set that up outside my new house and slowly move my belongings out of the storage unit, heat treat them in the Dr. Infrared tent, then bring them inside my new house and for good measure I will also place the ePro 400 inside the Dr. Infrared tent to compensate for the cold winter temperatures outside to ensure the internal temperature of the tent is at the 150 degrees Fahrenheit required to kill the bugs.

So apologies for that long explanation but that is why I don't feel I can use a professional company because those companies charge a lot of money for their treatment and they probably wouldn't be able to treat all three of my locations for an affordable sum.

**So here's my main question and concern.** My apartment has a gas line that is used for my oven and I'm wondering if anything needs to be done with that before I can heat treat my apartment. The apartments temperature will be at 150 degree Fahrenheit for almost an entire day.

Comment: Ask your landlord about you using this before buying.  Have to have their okay, but I doubt that you will get it.  Do you even have enough separate circuits in the apartment to use this, not outlets, circuits.

Comment: Good question. I just checked my breaker box and I have four open circuits for my outlets. Two of the circuits are 15 amp and the other two are 20 amp so that's just enough. Thanks! As for my landlord he can go ___ himself.

Comment: Those units in the picture look like plastic.  Would be worried about them melting and burning the place down, instead of the gas pipe which should be metal,  also are made in China and might not be safe anyway.

Comment: @crip659 those units are sold from an America company and they are designed for this. There are many plastics designed to withstand heat. And even plastics that are not designed to withstand heat do not start to melt until 212 degrees Fahrenheit which is far higher than is necessary to kill bugs. The units are safe.

Comment: @KyleBridenstine ...or the the land-lord can sue you. but I expect that the landlord wants an apartment that is not infested, and by using this system you provide that.

Comment: Professional bed bug treatment companies also own shipping containers with heat treat equipment. They can drop one in your new driveway.

Comment: Seems a lot of potential problems to avoid using a little ( $10 ) Malathion insecticide. 24 hours will not be enough time for heat to penetrate clothing in drawers, bedding , etc.

Comment: @blacksmith37 insecticide won’t kill bird mites I’ve already tried every insecticide known to man.

Comment: Agree, insecticide likely won't work.   But there are miticides; I have not used them as the only mites I have killed were on spruce trees and mineral oil/baby oil emulsion spray killed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called the [Green Tech Heat](https://www.greentechheat.com) company and they said that it's safe to use their [ePro 400 XP Electric Heat Bed Bug package](https://www.greentechheat.com/cart.php#!/ePro-400XP-Electric-Heat-Bed-Bug-Package/p/400548567/category=14085535) in an apartment that has a natural gas line for the oven. They said the gas line doesn't need to be turned off or anything special.

They also said that the heater is designed to be placed on carpet so you don't have to be concerned about a fire hazard with it catching your carpet on fire either. They said that if I wanted to use this in my car it would be fine sitting on top of the cars carpeting and that if I want to I can choose to just connect three of the plugs so that it has slightly less power running to it for when I treat my car (but that's optional if I'm concerned about it harming my vehicle). They also said if I'm really concerned about it in the car I can place a floor tile under the unit but they said it's not necessary because the units designed to be safe on top of carpeting.

A few other tips they gave me was to make sure I "heat soak" the rooms individually to ensure a thorough heat treatment and that the longer it heat soaks a room the better results; he said one plus side to owning your own unit is that you have the opportunity to heat soak a room for a longer period of time. He also suggested using painters tape to seal up any AC vents and doors when treating an individual room.

Answer (score 0):

Welding at a gas line is done with the line full of gas.

In some location, the line MUST be full of gas as safety rule.

It sounds paradox, but the gas needs oxygen from the air to burn or explode - which is missing in the gas tube if filled with gas only.

But of course,  the best way is to ask the gas supplier by mail to get a written statement.
And the insurance company as well.

As for the heat treatment:
There are alternative devices which produce much heat and are much less expensive. And are heat proofed to 65°C.

F.e., room dryers running on gas bottles or diesel/oil (gas bottle to be placed outside of the heated room), which are used in the construction industry may produce 12kW of heat or more, independent on the electric net limitations.

With those electric heaters in the photo, it max be difficult to reach the target temperature of 65°C, because of power limitations.

Hot air guns/hairdryers can output 200°C hot air or more to treat small things or sensitive items where only the surface and pockets should be heated for some seconds.

Comment: Welding of gas lines can be done containing gas that is FLOWING.